# d3 click event is stopped with zoom and pan layer

Tags: d3.js

Trying to create an example with zoom and pan and selectable nodes. The problem I'm facing is that when rect responsible for zooming is above the circles representing the nodes this layer stops the click event. When I move the zoom layer under the circles as in the example below the zoom and pan features stop working when I'm over a circle. I want to be able to zoom and pan everywhere in the svg area, while I want to be able to select the nodes clicking on their visual representation.

```
    d3.json("/miserables.json")
        .then((graph) => {
            var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed).scaleExtent([1 / 10, 30]);
            var rect = svg.append( "rect" )
            var g = svg.append( "g" );

            var zz = graph.nodes.map( function ( n ) { return n.value } );
            var max = d3.max( zz );
            var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain( [0, max] ).range( [5, 50] );

            var zz1 = graph.links.map( function ( n ) { return n.value } );
            var max1 = d3.max( zz1 );
            var scale1 = d3.scaleLinear().domain( [0, max1] ).range( [0, 50] );

            for ( var xx in graph.links )
            {
                xx.value = scale1( xx.value );
            }

            var link = g
                .attr("class", "links")
                .selectAll("line")
                .data(graph.links)

            var node = g
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr( "r", function ( d ) { return scale( d.value ); } )
                .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return d.x })
                .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return d.y })
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                .on("click", function(d){
                    self.emitter.fire(consts.EVENT_SHOW_NODE_INFO, self.component, {_id : d.id});
                });

            rect
                .attr( "width", width )
                .attr( "height", height )
                .style( "fill", "none" )
                .style( "pointer-events", "all" )
                .call(zoom)
                .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(400, 200).scale(0.1));

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { var arr = d.id.split(":"); let t = arr[arr.length-1]; return t; });

            simulation
                .nodes(graph.nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation.force("link")
                .links(graph.links);

            function zoomed()
            {
                if ( g ) {
                    g.attr( "transform", d3.event.transform );
                }
            }

            function ticked() {
                link
                    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

                node
                    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured how to do it. I moved the circles on the zoomable layer. Now everything works as magic. I'm posting only the modifications:

```
            var zoomable_layer = svg.append( "g" );

            // var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed).scaleExtent([1 / 10, 30]);
            var zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([1 / 10, 30])
                .on("zoom", () => {
                    zoomable_layer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform )
                });

            var zz = graph.nodes.map( function ( n ) { return n.value } );
            var max = d3.max( zz );
            var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain( [0, max] ).range( [5, 50] );

            var zz1 = graph.links.map( function ( n ) { return n.value } );
            var max1 = d3.max( zz1 );
            var scale1 = d3.scaleLinear().domain( [0, max1] ).range( [0, 50] );

            for ( var xx in graph.links )
            {
                xx.value = scale1( xx.value );
            }

            svg.call(zoom);
            svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width/2, height/2).scale(0.1));

            var link = zoomable_layer
                .attr("class", "links")
                .selectAll("line")
                .data(graph.links)

            var node = zoomable_layer
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr( "r", function ( d ) { return scale( d.value ); } )
                .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return d.x })
                .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return d.y })
                .attr("cursor", "pointer")
                .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                .on("click", function(d){
                    self.emitter.fire(consts.EVENT_SHOW_NODE_INFO, self.component, {_id : d.id});
                });

            svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", (200))
                .attr("y", height-20)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .style("font-style", "italic")
                .style('fill', 'orange')
                .text("Scroll to zoom in and out and explore the clusters of entities.");

            node.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { var arr = d.id.split(":"); let t = arr[arr.length-1]; return t; });
```